# how to create MVC Razor view dropdown having id and text inside the <option>tag?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to create a dropdown  using MVC And Raxor view.
Although i am able to make a dropdown but i don't knoew how to set id and value inside dropdown  tag.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    SelectList dd = new SelectList(new[] { "Option1", "Option2" });//i want to set id 1 and 2 for Option1 and 2 respectively         
    ViewBag.dd = dd;
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
   @Html.DropDownList("vimalDD",new SelectList(new[]{"VImal","Raturi"} ))
    @Html.DropDownList("vimalDD", (SelectList)ViewBag.dd)
    @Html.DropDownList("Selected", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.dd, "First Option", new { name = "Name", id = "id" })
    @Html.DropDownList("vimalDD", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.dd , " -- Select -- ", new { id = "Job_DefaultProfitCenter" })
    @Html.DropDownList("vimalDD", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.dd, "--Choose Your City--")
```

I want dropdown output as:

```
<select id="anything" name="Anything">
<option id="1">option1</option>
<option id="2">option2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Create a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and set the `Value` and `Text` properties.

Comment: will you kindly write the code syntax , for creating IEnumerable<SelectListItem>. and where it has to be created inside controller or view @Stephen Muecke

Comment: In the controller - `ViewBag.dd = new List<SelectListItem>{ new SelectListItem{ Value = "1", Text = "option1" }, new SelectListItem{ Value = "2", Text = "option2" } }` and in the view `@Html.DropDownList("vimalDD", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.dd)` but all this is awful practice. Use a view model and the strongly typed `DropDownListFor()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    ViewBag.dd = new List<SelectListItem>{ new SelectListItem{ Value = "1", Text = "option1" }, new SelectListItem{ Value = "2", Text = "option2" } }
    return View();
}
```

inside View Page :

```
@Html.DropDownList("vimalDD", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.dd)
```